# Moving WPF application to Android

Tags: c#, android, wpf

Im not sure if this is the best place for this question so please let me know if not. I have recently created a pretty simple WPF application that has a link to a SQL Database and allows information to be added, updated and deleted.

I want to port the application so I can use it on my Android phone but am unsure about the easiest way to do this. Im aware I could write a completely new application but Im wondering if there is a way I could easily use all the code ive already written or my Windows app? That way it would also make any updates/code changes easier?

Any thoughts

Comment: Xamarin is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Significant parts of your code **should** be pretty much reusable without major changes on mobile clients **IF and only IF** you properly implemented MVVM (which is the right way to write WPF) as opposed to throwing up a bunch of database access code in your window1.xaml.cs code behind file.

Comment: In the first instance I did throw everything into the .cs code behind the MainWindow. Ive since had my eyes opened to the wonders of MVVM so am in the process of re-writing. The end game is a mobile app though. Thanks guys